# Rewriting a url in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Basically my current link is:

`https://www.mysite.co.uk/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7`

how can i rewrite this url to:

`https://www.mysite.co.uk/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6-mystring/segment7`

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^\/segment1\/segment2\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*) \/segment1\/segment2\/$3\/$4\/$5\/$6-mystring\/$7 [r=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: I'm not very experienced with htaccess and after reading through that i still haven't a clue where i'm going wrong, the info looks solid but perhaps lost on me because of my experience, thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to escape `/` in rewrite rules and make leading slash optional as `.htaccess` files don't match leading `/`. Also you can greatly reduce capturing groups in your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(segment1/segment2/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/(?![^/]*-mystring)[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(/.*)?$ /$1-mystring/$2$3 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: This almost works thank you, it is repeating the string over and over again in the url though.

Comment: For example i am now getting:
https://www.mysite.co.uk/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring-mystring/segment7

Comment: sorry if it spammed you i just tried to tag you in my comment. The url structure is the exact same however it's loading the page now, previously i was getting a too many redirects error. Just need to trim that url to only show the string once. Thanks!

Comment: Once you clear your browser cache and if you keep this rule at top of your .htaccess this rule works. On my apache it redirected `http://localhost/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7` to this: `http://localhost/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6-mystring/segment7`